# pycharm can't find haystack but terminal can

Tags: django, pycharm, django-haystack

Trying to install Haystack following django-haystack documentation the basic tutorial for installation and configuration but a problem faces me as I can't import haystack in Search-Indexes py file 
Haystack is installed the env and in the root

## Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'haystack',
'products',
]
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
            'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'

        },
    }
```

## Search_Indexes.py

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes <<error can't find indexes
```

yet in -->

## >>Terminal in my env

```
(amirshop) amir@amir-In######:~/####/#####$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from haystack import indexes
>>> indexes.
indexes.BasicSearchIndex(               indexes.FacetDateField(                 indexes.NgramField(                     indexes.__package__                     indexes.get_identifier(
indexes.BooleanField(                   indexes.FacetDateTimeField(             indexes.SearchField(                    indexes.__reduce__(                     indexes.get_model_ct(
```

What is the problem or precisely where?

Comment: Did you point your pycharm to virtualenv's python?

Comment: yes the terminal is the terminal of pycharm

Comment: No. I mean. Settings -> Project myproject -> Project Interpreter ?

Comment: Yeah Yeah  @SardorbekImomaliev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

just I point again my pycharm to myenv in the usr bin
using this steps: [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html) Thanks @Sardorbek Imomaliev
1 -

1. Settings (ctrl + Alt +S)
2. project:Name
3. Interpreter
4. Choose your interpreter and see installed packages

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your notes